# Prove $\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{2^{-k}}{k} = \log 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

While working on a harder double sum, I (erroneously) reduced it to the sum below, which I recognized numerically to rapidly converge to $\log 2$.

> Prove $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{2^{-k}}{k} = \log 2$$

The cute observation is that if you replace the $2^{-k}$ with $(-1)^{-k}$ you get the same result (only now the convergence becomes conditional).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Highlights:

For $\;|x|<1\;$ :

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\implies -\log(1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$$

and now substitute $\;x=\frac12\;$ ...

Answer (score 5):

By comparison with the geometric series with $1/2$ as common ratio, the series in the question converges absolutely, so we can write

\begin{align}
& \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{-k}}{k} \\
=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty  2^{-k} \int_0^1 x^{k-1} dx \\
=& \int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^\infty  2^{-k} x^{k-1} dx \tag{Fubini's Theorem} \\
=& \frac12 \int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{k-1} dx \\
=& \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x/2} dx \\
=& \left[ -\ln\left|1-\frac{x}{2}\right| \right]_0^1 \\
=& \ln2.
\end{align}

Comment: This is very, very beautiful. +1 BTW, What Fubini's theorem? I know the integral version. Do you have some link to it?

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for upvote.  I'm actually applying [Fubini-Tonelli's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) (since all terms are nonnegative) on the product of Lebesgue measure and counting measure for the interchange of infinte sum and integral sign.

Comment: Thanks. I think I see: the (discrete) counting measure as "an integral" on that sum and then F.T. usual theorem. Very nice indeed.