# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{-k}}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$ without evaluating either sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Show that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{-k}}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}
$$
without evaluating either sum.

This is inspired by
[Prove $\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{2^{-k}}{k} = \log 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2719008/prove-lim-m-to-infty-sum-k-1m-frac2-kk-log-2).

This, of course,
follows from
$\ln(1+x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^{k}}{k}
$
for
$-1 \lt x \le 1$.
But I am not allowing that!

What I am looking for
is a way to
manipulate one of the series
to convert it to
the other.

Comment: If you are asking the question, it should be up to the people answering it to choose their own methods to solve it.

Comment: I often see restrictions on the answer, such as a combinatoric proof.

Comment: @Carl Mummert: Besides, as the OP, I can accept whatever answer I like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Euler transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform) on $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}$:
$$\begin{split}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{k+1}}\left.\Delta^k\frac{1}{m+1}\right\rvert_{m=0}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{k+1}}\left.\frac{(-1)^k}{\binom{m+k+1}{k}}\right\rvert_{m=0}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{k+1}}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}(k+1)}\text{.}\end{split}$$

(The key equality

$$\Delta^k\frac{1}{m+1}=\frac{(-1)^k}{\binom{m+k+1}{k}}$$
can be shown inductively.)

Comment: Very nice !  Can you show in a similar way that $\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{(1/2)^k}{k}=1/2 \cdot \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{(3/4)^k}{k}$ ?

Comment: I like that this avoids using an integral, which is the definition of ln.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{2^{-k} \over k} & =
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}2^{-k}\int_{0}^{1}t^{k - 1}\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{t \over 2}^{k}\,{\dd t \over t} =
\int_{0}^{1}{t/2 \over 1 - t/2}\,{\dd t \over t}
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over 2 - t} \,\,\,\stackrel{t\ \mapsto\ 1 - t}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over 1 + t} =
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}\,t^{k}\,\dd t =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}\int_{0}^{1}t^{k}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k + 1} =
\bbx{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k - 1} \over k}}
\end{align}

Comment: Wow, very nice!!!

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer, only some thoughs about it, too long for a comment.*

$\begin{align}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2N}\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}n &=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\left(\dfrac 1{2n-1}-\dfrac 1{2n}\right) =\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\left(\dfrac 1{2n}+\dfrac 1{2n-1}-\dfrac 1{n}\right)\\ &=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2N} \dfrac 1n-\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac 1n =\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{2N}\dfrac 1n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac 1{n+N}\\ &=\dfrac 1N\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac 1{1+\frac nN}\xrightarrow{\text{Riemann sum}}\int_0^1\dfrac{dt}{1+t}=\ln(2)\end{align}$

Now with your problem you get $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac 1{2^kk}=\int_0^1\dfrac{\mathop{du}}{2-u}$

Both integrals are equal by the change of variable $x=1-u$

We can also easily report in the Riemann sum to get $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac 1{2N-n}=\sum\limits_{n=N}^{2N-1}\dfrac 1n$ and get back to the alternate series.

But I do not see a direct way to go from $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac 1{2N-n}$ to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{??}\dfrac 1{2^kk}$, I suppose that since the convergence is greatly accelerated, we have to sum a lot of $(-1)^k$ terms for each single $2^{-k}$ one...

I too wonder if we can prove this directly without passing via the integrals.