# Techniques for Evaluating/Bounding Sums over Lattices

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

The problem prompting this question is the following from [Koblitz's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387979662) *Introduction to Elliptic Curves and Modular Forms 2nd ed*, 1.6.1 (paraphrased):

Show the sum $\sum_{l\in \mathbb{Z}[i], \textrm{ }l\neq 0} \frac{1}{l^4}$ is a nonzero real number.

I can show the sum is a real number, but am stumped on showing it is nonzero. I can bound the sum, but this bound is not helpful. Since the sum is absolutely convergent, we can rearrange the terms in the series in the following way:
\begin{align}\sum_{l\in \mathbb{Z}[i], \textrm{ }l\neq 0} \frac{1}{l^4} = 4\sum_{b=1}^\infty \frac{1}{b^4} + 4\sum_{a>0}\sum_{b>0} \frac{1}{(a+bi)^4} = 4\left(\zeta(4)+ \sum_{a>0}\sum_{b>0} \frac{1}{(a+bi)^4}\right). \end{align}

I got the right hand side by "rationalizing" the denominator to get $\frac{a^4+b^4-6a^2+b^2 +i(4ab^3-4a^3b)}{(a^2+b^2)^4}$, since the real part depends only on squares of $a,b$ we can sum over just the first quadrant and simply multiply this sum by 4. Perhaps this is the wrong approach, and there is an easier way.

More generally, I am interested in learning more about techniques which can be used to either evaluate sums over lattices or bound them (particularly from below). A resource with some worked out examples would be great, as well as some tricks you have found useful. An analogue for such a trick (for a single sum) might be something like GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會's answer to the question [Prove $\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{2^{-k}}{k} = \log 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2719008/prove-lim-m-to-infty-sum-k-1m-frac2-kk-log-2).

While stackexchange has some questions about sums over lattices, most seem to be questions about convergence and not about techniques for evaluating them more generally.

Comment: The thing that occurs to me is to use the that that expression has a (convergent) Euler product expansion... Is this in the ballpark of ideas appropriate in your context?

Comment: The naive answer is that it is obvious it is non-zero from a numerical check (made rigorous with an estimate of the convergent rate). It is much more difficult to prove that a given series is $0$ than non-zero. But this series is also very special due to Paul Garrett's comment.

Comment: @paulgarrett Another product: $\Delta(i)$ using that $G_6(i)=0$

Comment: @reuns, ah, yes, a classic! Great stuff! :)

Comment: There is also the connexion to $B(1/2,1/4)$ computing $\int_0^1 dz = \int_0^1 \frac{d\wp_i(z)}{\wp_i'(z)}=\int_C \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4 x^3+g_2(i) x}}dx$ where $C$ is a certain contour

Comment: @paulgarrett Since this series is an Eisenstein series evaluated at z=i, your comment makes me wonder if all Eisenstein series have convergent Euler products. Perhaps that is a separate question in its own right. Thank you and reuns for the instructive comments.

Comment: @C.Moore No. $G_{2k}(\tau)$ has an Euler product iff $\tau = a+b\sqrt{d}$ is a quadratic integer, $\Bbb{Z}[\tau]$ is a PID and $|\Bbb{Z}[\tau]^\times|$ divides $2k$.

Comment: One example-family of "period of Eisenstein series" that has Euler products, extending @reuns' comment wherein we depend on class-number one, consists of sums of evaluations at the (finite) set of Heegner points attached to a negative fundamental discriminant. More subtly, corresponding finite sums of integrals over geodesics corresponding to ideal classes (etc.) of _real_ quadratic fields give Euler products. :)